# Aggregating MySQL rows by day

Tags: mysql

I have a MySQL table like this:

```
Payments
+----+---------------------+---------+
| id | date (sorted DESC)  | payment |
+----+---------------------+---------+
|  5 | 2010-03-26 00:00:01 |  100.00 |
|  4 | 2010-03-19 00:00:02 |   55.12 |
|  3 | 2010-03-19 00:00:01 |   20.00 |
|  2 | 2010-03-12 00:00:02 |  320.00 |
|  1 | 2010-03-12 00:00:01 |   64.56 |
+----+---------------------+---------+
```

**How can I aggregate the total payments by day?**

Payments are inserted into the table every week, but they aren't always the exact same time as you can see. Can aggregation by day be done natively in MySQL?

The desired result would be:

```
+------------+----------------+
| date       | total payments |
+------------+----------------+
| 2010-03-26 |         100.00 |
| 2010-03-19 |          75.12 |
| 2010-03-12 |         384.56 |
+------------+----------------+
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: In your example you aggregate by day, this is much easier and way better defined than "give or take a few seconds".

Comment: I see what you mean. Edited to make it clearer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do 2 things, change the datetype to date, so just storing the date (this might not be possible in your situation).
Or you can group by reforming the date value so its just the date.

```
select date(date), sum(payment)
from payments
group by date(date)
order by date(date) desc
```

Comment: +1, This could've been my answer if I knew aggregating by date will do (see comment to the question) ;-)

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), date , 102) as date,sum(payment ) as total_payment
FROM Payments
GROUP BY  CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), date , 102) 
ORDER BY  CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), date , 102)
```

should be ok

Answer (score 0):

You can group by a function call on the date, so convert the full datetime to just the date part and group by that, so long as the date is in the select, it should be legal.